# Most accurate translation of Euclid's Elements

Tags: geometry, reference-request

Which is the most accurate translation of the Elements by Euclid? I have found manybtranslations but there seem to be some differences in each version. I would like to know which is the closest to the original.

Comment: Could you maybe provide some examples of differences you've found?

Comment: Are we considering only translations into English?

Comment: Servaes: I can read French and English, but I am a native speaker if Urdu. I'd like a translation in any of these, though I doubt that there's an Urdu version of Euclid.

Comment: See also the web-site linked to this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578420/which-translation-to-read-of-euclid-elements).

Comment: In fact, that is one of the translations I had in mind in asking this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding English, I think that Heath's edition :

> Thomas Heath, [The Thirteen Books of Euclid's Elements](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486600882) (1908 - Dover reprint)

in three volumes, with huge apparatus of notes and comemnts, it is still "the best one".

Comment: Is there any major difference in this edition and the original first edition in the public domain?

Comment: @ABajaj - I do not think so; it seems to me that it is a reprint of the Cambridge ed of 1908.

Answer (score 2):

I think that only Sir Thomas Heath's translation :

"The Thirteen Books of The Elements: Volume 1: Books 1 and 2

Paperback: 443 pages

Publisher: Dover Publications Inc.; 2nd edition edition (2 Jan 2000)

ISBN-10: 0486600882
ISBN-13: 978-0486600888 "

really amounts to something, but to say it is accurate, you may say it contains to much comment to be accurate. (Be prepared for 1 page translation followed by many pages comment per proposition)

Ps the ISBN is only of volume 1, There is also a volume 2 and 3

Comment: The Green Lion edition of this translation removes essentially all of Heath's commentary. It's also extremely well typeset and formatted, and contains all 13 books in a single volume.

Comment: Would I be missing anything if I get this edition which doesn't have the commentary?

Comment: @ABajaj - it depends... Are you more interested in the math side (in which case the commentary can be dispendes with) or in the historical side (in which case I think it is very very useful) ?

Comment: @ABajaj - if you are more interested in the math side, this is very very useful "commntary" : Robin Hartshorne, [Geometry: Euclid and Beyond](http://www.amazon.com/Geometry-Euclid-Beyond-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/0387986502) (2005).

Comment: Mauro ALLEGRANZA: Are there any prerequisites for reading that? I only know some naive set theory, calculus, high school algebra and geometry.

Comment: @ABajaj - no; Euclid's *Elements* is the first complete math textbook in the human history; thus, strictly speaking, it requires no prerequisite at all ... Hartshorne is a good book, with an "mixed" historical-mathematical approach. At the beginning is not difficult; of course, it "moves" towards a certain degree of abstraction. You can browse at the Intro in Amazon, through the link in my comment above.

Comment: @ABajaj I've been reading the version without commentary and I find it to be very readable and comprehensible.